# Import Directive into Component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to import `Directive` into `Component`? I want to avoid importing into `ngModule.declarations`.

I am following [CustomDirective for Telerik Angular Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/data-binding/automatic-operations/#toc-custom-directives). It is suggested to populate grid with customDirective, but I will need this directive in only one component, so I want to avoid importing in ngModule, to avoid name collisions.

**Edited:**
I tried with `viewProviders` but it does not work. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dYx3aFxEATDJkAjrzEXk?p=preview) is plunkr that works (directive imported in ngModule):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HighlightDirective
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lpE2Eq7HVtjRHOxgBriw?p=preview) is plunkr which doesn't work. (directive imported in Component):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  viewProviders: [HighlightDirective]
})
export class AppComponent {
  color: string;
}
```

Comment: If you want to avoid name collisions then create dedicated `@NgModule` https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#feature-modules `There are conflicting directives`

Comment: I also see no point in importing in NgModule if only one or two component will need it.

Comment: @Fredrik Lundin wrote the right answer here

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is entirely possible, you can use `Component` decorator's `viewProviders` option, like this:

```
@Component({
   template: '<div myCustomDirective>Hello</div>',
   selector: 'app-hello',
   viewProviders: [MyCustomDirective]
})
export class Component {}
```

But I should warn this is not really a best practice, trty to stick with the modules.

Comment: `viewProviders: [MyCustomDirective]` This directive has nothing to do with template. It's provider not directive now. We have to declare directive in `@NgModule`

Comment: @yurzui I think I understand. Does that means it can't be done.

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dYx3aFxEATDJkAjrzEXk?p=preview) works and [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lpE2Eq7HVtjRHOxgBriw?p=preview) does not. Changes are in app.module.ts and app.component.ts.